# calendarsForEntityType return empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekeventstore

I am experiencing a weird behaviour by the EKEventStore.

1. Started the app and didn't allow access to my Calendars.
2. Obviously I couldn't approach my Calendars as "Granted = NO"...
3. Killed the app.
4. Went to settings and enabled access to Calendars.
5. Ran the app again, now I get "Granted = YES" but [self.store calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent] returns an empty array.

I've made sure self.store is not nil and that I do have Calendars objects in my Calendars. What else could it be?

Comment: Try to checked for type `EKEntityTypeReminder` also. Probably none of your calendar object is of `EKEntityTypeEvent` type.

Comment: Nope... Something else?

Answer (score 0):

The issue obviously is in your `self.store`, how do you construct it ?

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKSourceClassRef/index.html) you have to retrieve the `sources` property of EKEventStore object, which is an array of `EKSource` type, on which you can call `calendarsForEntityType`

> An instance of the EKSource class represents the account that a
>   calendar belongs to. You do not create instances of this class. You
>   retrieve EKSource objects from an EKEventStore object. Use the sources
>   property to get all the EKSource objects for an event store, and use
>   the methods in this class to access properties of the source object.